# How to remove multiple returns from this function

Tags: c, list, recursion, return, ansi-c

i have written a function that calculates the intersection of two sorted linked lists (in a recursive way), but i need to remove those "return" inside the if statement and readapt the code without them. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

```
t_nodo *intersezione_insieme(t_nodo *insieme_A, t_nodo* insieme_B)
{ 
    t_nodo *tmp;
    if (insieme_A == NULL || insieme_B == NULL) {
        tmp = NULL; 
    }
    else if (insieme_A->info < insieme_B->info) {
            return intersezione_insieme(insieme_A->succ, insieme_B);
    }
    else if (insieme_A->info > insieme_B->info) {
            return intersezione_insieme(insieme_A, insieme_B->succ);
    }
    else 
    {
        tmp = (t_nodo*)malloc(sizeof(t_nodo));
        tmp->info = insieme_A->info;
        tmp->succ = intersezione_insieme(insieme_A->succ, insieme_B->succ);
    }
    return tmp; 
}
```

Comment: You could always have a variable hold their data, then return the variable

Comment: Why not always use `tmp` to return the value? Replace the two `return intersezione_insieme...` for `tmp = intersezione_insieme...` and you're good.

Comment: `How to remove multiple returns from this function` if your are using `vi editor` you can use `dd` command.

Comment: Martin Véronneau oh my god, how could i not think about it? I tried everything but the simplest thing... Thank you very much

Comment: Presumably someone told you that it was "bad style" to have multiple returns.  Please know that this is an opinion, not a fact.  It can be persuasively argued that your original code is perfectly fine, and that the version with the `tmp` variable is poorer.

Comment: @SteveSummit When it comes to recursion, it happens to be a fact. A compiler cannot likely optimize this code at all, since it isn't tail recursion. Meaning that simple code that could have been written as a simple fast loop, will instead perform horribly, horribly slow, just because someone decided to use recursion.

Comment: @Lundin `return intersezione_insieme` is a tail recursion by definition: [a tail call is a subroutine call performed as the final action of a procedure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call). And this variant is perfectly optimized by modern compilers. Keeping result in `tmp` and returning later means, that stack frame of current function can't be freed prior to subroutine call, which may lead to literal stack overflow in case of deep recursion, try avoiding this whenever possible.

Comment: Thank you all for the response! I really appreciate that

Comment: @nnovich-OK No, it is not perfectly optimized by modern compilers. https://godbolt.org/z/8ArJ-l. The modern compiler did a poor job and did not optimize the recursion at all. A loop would have been hundred times better. More disassembly and less computer science ivory towers.

Answer (score 1):

Like it was outlined in the comments, having multiple returns in a function is not necessarily bad form. It all depends on the context. For example, a long-ish function might check for a few "return now" conditions before executing the function's code.

But I can see readability being increase by having a single return statement in your function.

Here's my humble suggestion :

```
t_nodo *intersezione_insieme(t_nodo *insieme_A, t_nodo* insieme_B)
{ 
    t_nodo *temporaneoNodo;
    if (insieme_A == NULL || insieme_B == NULL) {
        temporaneoNodo = NULL; 
    }
    else if (insieme_A->info < insieme_B->info) {
            temporaneoNodo = intersezione_insieme(insieme_A->succ, insieme_B);
    }
    else if (insieme_A->info > insieme_B->info) {
            temporaneoNodo = intersezione_insieme(insieme_A, insieme_B->succ);
    }
    else 
    {
        temporaneoNodo = (t_nodo*)malloc(sizeof(t_nodo));
        temporaneoNodo->info = insieme_A->info;
        temporaneoNodo->succ = intersezione_insieme(insieme_A->succ, insieme_B->succ);
    }
    return temporaneoNodo; 
}
```

Comment: It _is_ necessarily bad form when it comes to recursion, since the compiler can fail the tail call optimization and produce crap: https://godbolt.org/z/8ArJ-l But then of course recursion in itself is bad form and the root of that problem.